# How to count the median, mean and percentile of all columns together and not separately using pySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a problem that I have a text file:

```
1   -0.087  0.019   -0.01   -0.046  -0.091  0.045
2   0.049   0.069   0.043   0.072   -0.021  -0.064
3   0.077   -0.079  -0.06   -0.021  -0.019  -0.096
4   0.026   0.07    -0.07   -0.035  0.072   0.088
5   0.038   0.046   -0.037  -0.008  0.03    0.091
6   0.005   0.032   -0.086  -0.038  0.091   0.023
7   0.038   0.046   -0.037  -0.008  0.03    0.091
8   0.005   0.032   -0.086  -0.038  0.091   0.023
9   0.052   0.022   -0.017  -0.006  -0.022  -0.059
10  -0.095  0.061   -0.042  0.057   0.012   0.023
```

which there are several columns.
In general, the scheme looks like the first column is identifiers (ID) and each subsequent column is numbers. I want to count the median, mean and percentile of all columns together and not separately using pySpark. Unfortunately, I do not know how to do this. I can count for each column separately, but not for all together.

Can someone suggest me something?

Comment: Have you tried `df.summary()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a final approach, I used the proposed solution by @ARCrow.

I created separate dataframes for each column.
After that I unioned them and then run the summary method for the resulting dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is that the number of whitespaces between values of columns are different across rows, and that complicates reading the file into a dataframe.

If you treat the file like a csv file with the separator character defaulted to `,`, this is what you get:
[image]

To separate the numerical values, you can try:

```
df = (df
      .withColumn('values_separated', f.expr('filter(split(_c0, " "), element -> element != "")'))
     )
```

The output looks like this:
[image]

Now to separate the values in the "values_separated" array into columns:

```
df = (df
      .select(*[f.element_at(f.col('values_separated'), i).alias('col_' + str(i)) for i in range(1, 8)])
     )
```

And then running the summary method:

```
df.summary().show()
```

The output will be:

```
+-------+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|summary|             col_1|               col_2|               col_3|              col_4|               col_5|               col_6|               col_7|
+-------+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|  count|                10|                  10|                  10|                 10|                  10|                  10|                  10|
|   mean|               5.5|              0.0108|              0.0318|            -0.0402|-0.00710000000000...|0.017300000000000003|0.016499999999999997|
| stddev|3.0276503540974917|0.057807727280471184|0.042993022689734206|0.03925925227113844| 0.04050089162255841|0.057988600412303255|  0.0683036520904182|
|    min|                 1|              -0.087|              -0.079|              -0.01|              -0.006|              -0.019|              -0.059|
|    25%|               3.0|               0.005|               0.022|              -0.07|              -0.038|              -0.021|              -0.059|
|    50%|               5.0|               0.026|               0.032|             -0.042|              -0.021|               0.012|               0.023|
|    75%|               8.0|               0.049|               0.061|             -0.017|              -0.006|               0.072|               0.088|
|    max|                 9|               0.077|                0.07|              0.043|               0.072|               0.091|               0.091|
+-------+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: in your solution you calculated the statistics per column but I do want to calculate statistics for all values in dataset together so probably six columns with values should e joined together but I do not know how to do it to treat all columns as one and then calculate statistics, do you know?

Comment: You can create separate dataframes for each column, union them, and then run the summary method for the resulting dataframe